# UNIKONG scales improperly (at 120dpi, at least)

Tags: feature-request, bug, unikong

On both of my computers (with vastly different sized screens) which use a higher DPI (120dpi), I find I have to reduce the zoom to 85% to see the entire game onscreen. The game looks fine when so scaled.

I would suggest that you check the [viewport height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248160/1802924) and [zoom factor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=devicepixelratio)*, and use that to figure out a maximum height. It might be good to do the same thing with width, if you want to handle portrait devices.

<sup>* There's an [old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers) about it, too, but it's significantly out of date.</sup>